# How do I remove old assets during an update?

Tags: ios, resources, assets

To make a long story short, we have released an app that has hundreds of images stored in the application bundle. The file structure for the images is something like:

```
/var/mobile/Applications/.../ApplicationName.app/Images 1.0/0001.png
/var/mobile/Applications/.../ApplicationName.app/Images 1.0/0002.png
```

We want to release an update to the app that replaces all of these images with our 2.0 assets:

```
/var/mobile/Applications/.../ApplicationName.app/Images 2.0/0001.png
/var/mobile/Applications/.../ApplicationName.app/Images 2.0/0002.png
```

The tricky part is that the new images are not a strict one-to-one replacement of the old images — we have added a few and removed a few. Unfortunately, it appears that you are unable to remove file from the app bundle and the update itself does nothing to change them either.

The primary reason we want to remove the old resources is that they take up quite a bit of space on disk. It doesn't seem good to have these old, unused files hanging around.

Comment: I've never really thought about this, but are you saying that when the user does an app update it keeps around files that were in the old bundle but not in the new one?

Comment: All of our in-house testing suggests this is the case. We haven't strictly tested an actual app store download.

Comment: That sounds really strange. Is this tested only with Build/Debug or with actually packaging up an IPA and installing with an ad hoc provisioning profile?

Comment: Try a full ad hoc install and see if the problem is real. I've noticed weird phenomena with asset retention when building straight to a development device. I suspect Xcode cuts corners and doesn't overwrite the whole bundle in order to reduce time to build and launch.